# How to use an IBOutlet from parent class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm working on an iOS and having some trouble accessing to an IBOutlet from a parent class, in this case a label with the life of the character.

My ViewController (parent) are like this:

```
@interface OpponentViewController : UIViewController {
IBOutlet UILabel *opponent_life;
IBOutlet OpponentView *opponentView;
}
@end
```

The OpponentView (child) class is where the character (image) reside and where player do all touch interaction. When the player touch OpponentView the label should be refreshed.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly you would like to update `opponent_life` when ever you detect a touch in `opponentView`. Here are two ways of assigning the label to the view so it can be used from `tocuhesBegan:withEvent:`

#### 1. Assigning the label to the view in IB

```
@interface OpponentView : UIView {
  IBOutlet UILabel *opponent_life;
}
```

In the nib file for `OpponentViewController` you change the type of the view from `UIView` to `OpponentView` and then connect the label to the outlet of the view.

#### 2. Assigning the label in `viewDidLoad`

```
@interface OpponentView : UIView {
  UILabel *opponent_life;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *opponent_life;
```

In `OpponentViewController'

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  opponentView.opponent_life = opponent_life;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OpponentView should be a subclass of something like UIImageView, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misinterpreting the problem you're having, but if you can't see the instance variables as outlets at all, you can try including `IBOutlet` in your property declarations. For example:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *opponent_life;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet OpponentView *opponentView;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code the `OpponentView` class is one which extends any class like `UIView` or `UIImageView` etc.

So you have to drag a `UIView` or `UIImageView`(based on the requirement) to the `OpponentViewController's` view in the `IBOutlet` from Library.

Then change the class in the "viewIdentity" in the inspector to `OpponentView`. and then you can link to the file owner.

So that you can solve your problem.